# Where do I ask about game physics alghorithm? (Stack Overflow/Maths/Physics)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My problem is that I have asked on Stack Overflow about a specific problem considering some function I need to write in my code, got on hold for too broad question, so I decided to delete the question and make sure I am asking it on right site.

My problem is that I need to algorithmically figure out how a non-zero mass object changes its position in space within a certain amount of time in an abstract physics model.

The model is based on the fact you have some specific **point in space P**, and a **rigid body** with **two physical forces** applied to it, of which **one is constant** and the **other one (F') is directed to point P** and its value is equal to given formula: |F'| = (d'/d)^x * |F|, where |F| is a constant force value, d' is distance between P and given rigid body, d is a distance constant and x is a constant number.

What I need to be calculated by my algorithm is **position and velocity** (as vector values) of a rigid body in space **after specific delta time**, knowing object's start position in space, its velocity, P coordinates and delta time; I want this to be calculated according to classical mechanics laws (and there is only one correct answer for each case, so the problem is as specific as it can only be). Also if you are in doubt, position and velocity apply to exactly the same problem in this case, so splitting it into two questions would be just duplicate, which is not allowed.

Basically, this problem can be asked on Stack Overflow, Maths or Physics:

- Stack Overflow - because I need an algorithm, but still due to the possibility to reduce this problem to out of coding, I decided that it is not the best place.
- Physics - because it heavily involves physical models.
- Math - because it will require knowledge of derivatives and integrals (which I seriously lack) to create a formula that can calculate the final position.

Sadly, this **cannot be separated to smaller problems** any further.

So, what is the best place to ask this?

Comment: Unless your problem is with the code itself, SO won't be the ideal place. And even if the problem only has a single solution, the question itself can still be too broad if it isn't clear what specifically *you* need help with. Honestly, it looks like this isn't a great fit for any site until it can be reduced down to a single aspect. You might want to try a site meant for broader questions, like Reddit, Quora, or Google+.

Comment: I can reduce this problem to "i need a formula [...]" and thus it is no longer code question, as I put emphasis in this question here, but it still applies to both areas of physics and maths

Comment: But the problem is "I need a formula" isn't a great fit for any sites here. If you take a step back, this question reads more of a "work request" than a specific problem that we can help you with. A more appropriate question would be something more along the lines of "I'm developing/writing a formula, I have x and y finished, but I can't figure out how to accomplish z. This is what I've tried, and this is what I'm stuck on". If you change it to that, it would likely be appropriate on the math site.

Comment: [gamedev.se] is another option.

Comment: @Pastardo what game engine are you using to create your game?